# How to fit a Polynomial to the natural log of itself

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, logarithms

Lets say I have a polynomial $a_{N}x^{N}\ ...\ a_{3}x^{3}+a_{2}x^{2}+ax\ +\ c$

Is there any method to compute $ ln(a_{N}x^{N}\ ...\ a_{3}x^{3}+a_{2}x^{2}+ax\ +\ c) $
such that the result is a new polynomial that best fits the natural log of the original polynomial. New coefficients could be added or removed in the process, but something quick to compute for large polynomials.

The range of input polynomial will be greater than 0.001 except for its end behavior

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: No, there isn't. The logarithm of your polynomial is just another function $f(x)$. To find a polynomial that resembles it, you can use the least squares method. The results will depend on the properties of $f$, on the domain, number of terms etc.